# transformers.js with whisper and return_timestamps

Tags: openai-whisper

I am new to both [transformers.js](https://github.com/xenova/transformers.js) and [whisper](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/whisper) trying to make [`return_timestamps`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.AutomaticSpeechRecognitionPipeline.__call__) parameter work...

I managed to customize [script.js](https://github.com/xenova/transformers.js/blob/main/assets/js/scripts.js#L447) from [transformer.js demo](https://xenova.github.io/transformers.js/) locally and added `data.generation.return_timestamps = "char";` around line ~447 inside GENERATE_BUTTON click handler in order to pass the parameter. With that change in place I am seeing timestamp appears as chunks (`result` in [worker.js](https://github.com/xenova/transformers.js/blob/main/assets/js/worker.js#L40)):

```
{
    "text": " And so my fellow Americans ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country.",
    "chunks": [
        {
            "timestamp": [0,8],
            "text": " And so my fellow Americans ask not what your country can do for you"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": [8,11],
            "text": " ask what you can do for your country."
        }
    ]
}
```

however the chunks are not "char level" granular as expected following the [`return_timestamps`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.AutomaticSpeechRecognitionPipeline.__call__) doc.

I am looking for ideas how to achieve char/word level timestamp granularity with transform.js and whisper. Do some models/tools need to be updated and/or rebuild?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creator of transformers.js here. Yesterday, I added support for word-level timestamps ([v2.4.0](https://github.com/xenova/transformers.js/releases/tag/2.4.0)). You can use it as follows:

```
import { pipeline } from '@xenova/transformers';

let url = 'https://huggingface.co/datasets/Xenova/transformers.js-docs/resolve/main/jfk.wav';
let transcriber = await pipeline('automatic-speech-recognition', 'Xenova/whisper-tiny.en', {
    revision: 'output_attentions',
});
let output = await transcriber(url, { return_timestamps: 'word' });
// {
//   "text": " And so my fellow Americans ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country.",
//   "chunks": [
//     { "text": " And", "timestamp": [0, 0.78] },
//     { "text": " so", "timestamp": [0.78, 1.06] },
//     { "text": " my", "timestamp": [1.06, 1.46] },
//     ...
//     { "text": " for", "timestamp": [9.72, 9.92] },
//     { "text": " your", "timestamp": [9.92, 10.22] },
//     { "text": " country.", "timestamp": [10.22, 13.5] }
//   ]
// }
```

Answer (score -1):

As of today (2023-04-06) openai whisper does not provide word or char level granularity for timestamps. There are some other projects based on whisper that do:

- https://github.com/linto-ai/whisper-timestamped
- https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp
- https://github.com/jianfch/stable-ts

Answer (score -1):

It took me a while to figure out the option for `whisper.cpp` to generate word-level timestamps, so sharing an example here (using command line took that comes with the library):

```
git clone git@github.com:ggerganov/whisper.cpp.git
cd whisper.cpp
bash ./models/download-ggml-model.sh base.en
make
./main -f samples/jfk.wav -oj --max-len 1
```

This is just a starting point.  The command above generates an empty string at the start, punctuation and spaces before words, which may be useful, depending on your use case.  Here's a snippet of the output:

```
    "transcription": [
        {
            "timestamps": {
                "from": "00:00:00,000",
                "to": "00:00:00,320"
            },
            "offsets": {
                "from": 0,
                "to": 320
            },
            "text": ""
        },
        {
            "timestamps": {
                "from": "00:00:00,320",
                "to": "00:00:00,370"
            },
            "offsets": {
                "from": 320,
                "to": 370
            },
            "text": " And"
        },
        {
            "timestamps": {
                "from": "00:00:00,370",
                "to": "00:00:00,690"
            },
            "offsets": {
                "from": 370,
                "to": 690
            },
            "text": " so"
        },
```